# Change link href/text to value of a textbox on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, href

I want to know if it's possible to have the text of an "a href" element to be the value of a textbox on a button click.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("#myLink").text($("#Coordinate1").val());
  $("#myLink").prop("href", "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + $("#Coordinate1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Coordinate1">
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<a id="myLink" href="#"><!-- THIS MUST BE VALUE OF "Coordinate1" --></a>
```

I hope the explanation is clear enought.

Thank you.

**SOLVED:** Added the code on the chosen answer below. Thanks everyone for your help all the solutions given by members worked how I wanted.

Comment: On what button click? There's no button in your code.

Comment: I didn't add button just wanted to explain the gist of it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem you want to do something like this.

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
 $("#myLink").text($("#Coordinate1").val());
  $("#myLink").prop("href", "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + $("#Coordinate1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<input type="text" id="Coordinate1">
<a id="myLink" href="#"><!-- THIS MUST BE VALUE OF "Coordinate1" --></a>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working perfectly with the button. BTW in my original code it was in a button element, I just didn't include it because I thought it wasn't necessary since you guys are experts! :) Thanks dude!

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code:

```js
function setLink() {
  var t = document.getElementById("Coordinate1").value;
  var h = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + t;
  var link = document.getElementById("myLink");
  link.href = h; //set link url
  link.innerText = h; //set link text (remove this line if you don't want it)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Coordinate1" oninput="setLink()">
<input type="button" value="get link" onclick="setLink()">
<div>
  <a id="myLink" href="#"></a><!-- THIS MUST BE VALUE OF "Coordinate1" -->
</div>
```

Comment: note that it will update the link instantly (as user type in textbox), so the [get link] button is not required anymore..! ;D hope to be usefull

Comment: Thank you! It did work :) I have already chosen the other answer as solution but will still upvote. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but you have to do it when the user click something or finishes typing the link, or some other event. Here I use a button:

```js
$("#change").click(function() {  // when the button is clicked, change the href to whatever in the input + the root, and change it's text to the value as well
  var value = $("#Coordinate1").val();
  $("#myLink").prop("href", "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + value) // change the href
              .text(value); // change the text content
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Coordinate1">
<a id="myLink" href="#">
  <!-- THIS MUST BE VALUE OF "Coordinate1" -->
</a>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good solution. Tested and is also working in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you were asking for. I took the code you already had and just placed it within the click of a button element I added to the page. Also be sure to give an actual text value inside the `a tag` or it won't be clickable to the user.

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  $("#myLink").prop("href", "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + $("#Coordinate1").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="Coordinate1">
<button id="update">update</button>
<a id="myLink" href="#">
Link
  <!-- THIS MUST BE VALUE OF "Coordinate1" -->
</a>
```